# How to get the value of an array？

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I am testing the models in zend project, I have a question about how to get the value of an array, I found it can not be done using `$array[index]`;

this is the find method I am testing:

```
   static function find($name, $order=null, $limit=null, $offset=null) {
        return self::_selectAndBind(
                get_class(),
                        self::getDefaultAdapter()
                        ->select()
                        ->from('user')
                        ->where('name = ?', array($name))
                        ->order($order)
                        ->limit($limit, $offset)
        );
    }
```

this is the test case for find():

```
public function testUser2CanFind() {
        $this->assertNotNull($this->_model->find('yes'));

        $this->assertEquals(1, count($this->_model->find('yes')));

        print_r($this->_model->find('yes'));
        //$this->assertEquals('admin',$this->_model->find('yes')[0]->login);
    }
```

I want to get the the value of login name, so we I `print_r($this->_model->find('yes'));` it gives:

```
......Array
(
    [0] => Application_Model_User2 Object
        (
            [_table:protected] => user
            [_primary:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                )

            [_primary_ai:protected] => id
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [created] => 2011-05-03 09:41:2
                    [login] => admin
                    [password_hash] => c8ebe700df11
                    [name] => yes
                    [surname] =>
                    [gender] =>
                    [street] =>
                    [postal_code] =>
                    [city] =>
                    [mobile] =>
                    [homephone] =>
                    [email] =>
                    [is_active] => 1
                )

            [_data_changed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_readonly:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                )

            [_db:protected] =>
        )

)
```

how could I get the value of  `[login] => admin`? I tried to use `$this->_model->find('yes')[0]`, but it gives error, can anyone help?

Comment: Deferenced array are not yet available, you can't use directly $this->_model->find('yes')[0]. You have to use a temporary variable.

Comment: What about `$this->_model->find('yes')->current()`. I assume that your find method returns a rowset.

Comment: @Marcin: As long as you can avoid it, you shouldnt call "magic methods" directly. `::current()` is called by the function `current()`. Use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$entity = current($this->_model->find('yes'));
echo $entity->login;
```

Update:

If there are more then one element in this list, use the usual iteration

```
foreach($this->_model->find('yes') as $entity) 
  echo $entity->login;
```

Comment: now there is only one element in this array, but what about if there are several elements in this array?